# Bootstrap Background Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so basically it will not display my background image. I have looked at all the other posts and none of them work. Here is the code.

Here is the Html. Note that the app.css and app.js are just bootstrap files renamed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Above is Important -->
  <meta name="description" content="HTML, CSS, BOOTSTRAP" />
  <meta name="author" content="James Mehltretter" />
  <title>Download Free HTML Templates</title>
  <link rel="stylsheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the part of the CSS that I edited.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
 background-image: url(background.png);

}
```

The JavaScript file is just generic bootstrap. Here is the link to the file I am actually using though.

[The Bootstrap JS](http://www.getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js)

Thank you.

Comment: The code itself is fine. There's something else missing in order for us to answer you. Can you provide the directory structure? As well as a console output (with network errors included)

Comment: I made the edit showing everything.

Answer (score 3):

**Your Body has no height and there's nothing in it to put a background on.**

Make sure your body has some height to it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);
  background-size: 1440px 800px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the image background.jpg exists within the *parent* directory of the directory that contains the css you've provided.

Comment: I have checked. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a 404 error on the file path in your javascript console? Also ditch the quotes. Don't think that's right.  I think w3Schools is wrong.  Here is Mozilla docs showing no quotes on URL:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: I am getting no errors. i also tried without the quotes, noting. Any other suggestions?

Comment: In Chrome, go to your Developer's Tool console, then go to Resources. Then on the left go to Frames and dig down until you see Images, then inside that folder make sure your image is loading.

Comment: This also might be a silly response, but if you are starting on a blank canvas, you may have to apply some height to your body or put something in it to see the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Check again with this code:

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
 background-image: url(../background.jpg);
 background-size: 1440px 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make the image cover the entire screen all the time use `HTML` or `HTML` and `BODY` together.

See working Snippet at Full page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Tokyo_by_night_2011.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: make it cover the entire screen

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have given the `height`, the image will show.
In this example, height: 100vh, which means it covers the whole screen.

```css
body{
        background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/fotos-kostenlos/gruene-wiese-hintergrund_1252-1098.jpg');
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

The best practice however is to set it to `cover` and `no-repeat`, so that the background image is shown only once despite the screen size.

```css
    body{
     background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/fotos-kostenlos/gruene-wiese-hintergrund_1252-1098.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 100vh;
    }
```